# Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code in this page? The layout does not work properly in Safari browser

Tags: browser, safari

I do some work on on old tables based site. It is being replaced but I would like it to work for now.

One of the pages in question is http://www.gdsofusa.com/marantec_garage_door_openers.html. When this page (and some others) is viewed in Safari 5.0 (7533.16) and probably others, the page content is off to the right.

I just need to fix this since about 15% of the traffic is Safari.

Please help!

Comment: Probably better asked on http://doctype.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by:

```
Removing "float:left" on your "tabs" div
Setting your "tabs" li's as "display:inline-block" instead of "display:inline"
```

HTH

Comment: Mr. R. Hill,

I want you to know you completely rock. The simple fix you offered did the trick. Since I am not an HTML / CSS guru I would have never seen it. Thank you for your help!

Cliff

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is always [validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gdsofusa.com%2Fmarantec_garage_door_openers.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this kind of problem is a mismatched end tag on an HTML element.

Try an HTML validator like http://validator.w3.org